# Implicit type discovery for generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types

I was wondering if C# supported implicit type discovery for class generics.

For example, such functionaly exists on method generics.

I can have the following method:

```
public void Foo<T>(T obj);
```

And call it like this:

```
int n = 0;
instance.Foo(n);
```

As you can see, I'm not specifying the `<int>` generic constraint. It's being implicitly discovered, because I passed an `int` value.

I want to accomplish something similiar on a class definition level:

```
internal interface IPersistenceStrategy<E, T> : IDisposable
    where E : UniqueEntity<T>
```

I want it to be defined as `IPersistenceStrategy<MyEntity>`, where `MyEntity is an UniqueEntity<int>`.

As you can see, the `T` type param, is being implicitly discovered from `MyEntity`.

However, this does not work. I have to supply the `T` param explicitly:

```
IPersistenceStrategy<MyEntity, int> myStrategy;
```

Why is this functionality not working? Is C# compiler not smart enough to discover my type param automatically?

Is there some way to accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: No you can't do this.

Comment: Simply because it is not in the specs.

Comment: To misquote Eric Lippert "Asking why a feature doesn't exist usually gets the answer "because nobody implmented it"." (he has said something along those lines). Usually it isn't implemented because it was deemed not to be worth the effort needed for whatever reason.

Comment: Your two examples really aren't the same at all - part of the problem is that generic type inference only works for generic methods, not generic types... but the second part is that I think you're expecting to specify *some* type arguments but not others, which isn't what you're doing in the first case. (Note that `int` isn't a constraint, it's a type argument... it's worth being careful with the terminology here, as generic type parameter constraints *do* exist...)

Comment: I understand, really. But it's harsh to hear. I refuse to believe I cannot accomplish this. I see `IPersistenceStrategy<MyEntity, int>` as a really ugly interface, while `IPersistenceStrategy<MyEntity>` as a simple and clear one.

Comment: Reality doesn't care if you refuse to believe in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no type inference in generic type declarations on initialization. You can only omit the generic argument when calling a generic method but it is not the case with initializing a generic type for example:

```
var list = new List { 2, 3, 4 };
```

Here you may expect compiler to see that you wanna create a list of int so there is no need to specify type argument.But it is not the case.

In your specific example let's assume compiler has inferred this :

```
IPersistenceStrategy<MyEntity> myStrategy;
```

as `IPersistenceStrategy<MyEntity,int>`  then what should happen if there is another declaration in the same assembly such as:

```
interface IPersistenceStrategy<T>  { }
```

Ofcourse this would cause an ambiguity. So that might be the one of the reasons why it is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

C# has type inference for methods, but not for constructors. This feature was proposed to be in C# 6 version, but seems was removed from release according to Mads Torgersen (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx).

Also have a look to [Languages features in C# 6 and VB 14](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20feature%20status&referringTitle=Home), i.e. there is no mention about it